converting from mysql query to eloquent laravel
Hello good am i would like to ask for advice on converting the following query to eloquent laravel.
my query in mysql
SELECT CONCAT(e.lastname,', ',e.firstname,' ',e.middlename) as full_name,
e.emp_id,
t.date,
t.time_in,
t.time_out,
TIME_FORMAT(time_in, "%r") as Ctime_in,    
TIME_FORMAT(time_out, "%r") as Ctime_out,    
TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in) as number_of_hrs    
FROM `employees` as e LEFT JOIN time_records as t  on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
where t.date = '2024-03-01' OR t.date IS NULL 
GROUP by e.emp_id; 

date range '2024-03-01' would be a variable in eloquent($day)
my code for eloquent so far
DB::table('employees')
    ->select(

        DB::raw("CONCAT(employees.lastname,', ',employees.firstname,' ',employees.middlename) as full_name"),

    'employees.emp_id',
    'time_records.date',
    'time_records.time_in',
    'time_records.time_out',
    DB::raw('TIME_FORMAT(time_in, "%r") as Ctime_in'),
    DB::raw('TIME_FORMAT(time_out, "%r") as Ctime_out'),
    DB::raw('TIMEDIFF(time_out,time_in) as number_of_hrs')



       )
    ->leftJoin('time_records', 'time_records.emp_id', '=', 'employees.emp_id')
    ->whereDate('date',$day)
    ->orwhereNull('date',$day)
    ->get();

this results gives me a different output from the mysql, i know my mistake is on the where date is null part
->whereDate('date',$day) \ dunno where to include the "OR t.date IS NULL"..

I found a solution though i just found a bug on my query afterwards but to solve my own question I use whereraw clause
->whereRaw('time_records.date = ? OR time_records.date IS NULL', [$day])

